# How to predict label for new input values using artificial neural network in python

Tags: neural-network, pickle, tf.keras, streamlit, multiclass-classification

I am new in machine learning. I am making a Streamlit app for multiclass classification using artificial neural network. My question is about the ANN model, not about the Streamlit. I know I can use MLPClassifier, but I want to build and train my own model. So, I used the following code to analyze the following data.[image: data]-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve, roc_auc_score, roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

df=pd.read_csv("./Churn_Modelling.csv")
#Drop Unwanted features
df.drop(columns=['Surname','RowNumber','CustomerId'],inplace=True)
df.head()

#Label Encoding of Categ features
df['Geography']=df['Geography'].map({'France':0,'Spain':1,'Germany':2})
df['Gender']=df['Gender'].map({'Male':0,'Female':1})

#Input & Output selection
X=df.drop('Exited',axis=1)
Y = df['Exited']
Y = df['Exited'].map({'yes':1, 'no':2, 'maybe':3})

#train test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3,random_state=12,stratify=Y)

#scaling 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
ss = StandardScaler()
X_train = ss.fit_transform(X_train)
Y_train = ss.fit_transform(Y_train)
X_test=ss.transform(X_test)

# build a model
#build ANN
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=30,activation='relu',input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=18,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
       
#create callback : -
cb=EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss",  #val_loss means testing error
    min_delta=0.00001, #value of lambda 
    patience=15,
    verbose=1,
    mode="auto", #minimize loss  #maximize accuracy
    baseline=None,
    restore_best_weights=False
)

trained_model=model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=10,
                        validation_data=(X_test,Y_test),
                        callbacks=cb,
                        batch_size=10
                        )

model.evaluate(X_train,Y_train)
print("Training accuracy :",model.evaluate(X_train,Y_train)[1])
print("Training loss :",model.evaluate(X_train,Y_train)[0])

model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test)
print("Testing accuracy :",model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test)[1])
print("Testing loss :",model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test)[0])


y_pred_prob=model.predict(X_test)
y_pred=np.argmax(y_pred_cv, axis=-1)

print(classification_report(Y_test,y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(Y_test,y_pred))

plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(Y_test,y_pred),annot=True,cmap="OrRd_r",
            fmt="d",cbar=True,
            annot_kws={"fontsize":15})
plt.xlabel("Actual Result")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Result")
plt.show()
```

Then, I will save the model either by using pickle as follows-

```
# pickle_out = open("./my_model.pkl", mode = "wb") 
# pickle.dump(my_model, pickle_out) 
# pickle_out.close()
```

or as follows-

```
model.save('./my_model.h5')
```

Now, I want to predict the label (i.e. 'yes', 'no', 'maybe' etc.) of output variable 'Existed' based on new input values (as shown in the following table) that will be provided by an user -
[image: new input to predict the class for output variable].

My question is that how should I save and load the model followed by predicting the labels for 'Existed' variable, so that it will automatically fill up the empty cell of Exited column with respective labels (i.e. 'yes', 'no', 'maybe' etc.).

I will appreciate your insightful comments on this post.

Comment: Are you able to load the model back?

Comment: @WesleyCheek yes I have reuploaded it.

Comment: If you have no problem loading the model from pickle, then you should be able to just use model.predict(X) where X is an array holding the features you want to predict on.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your model trained, you can simply run `model.predict` with the data you wish to predict on. Tricky parts of this process involve making sure this data is the right shape and that the indices match up.

I typically use this recipe:

Note that the features need to be in the exact same shape and order that the model was trained with.

```py
to_predict = df[features]
predictions = model.predict(
    to_predict.to_numpy().reshape(-1, len(features))
)
```

`predictions` should be the same length as `to_predict` and it will be an `np.array`. You can get this back into a `DataFrame` with the same indices as `to_predict` by using

```py
predictions = pd.DataFrame(
            predictions,
            columns="predicted_value",  # Anything you want
            index=to_predict.index,
        )
```

In your case, this should give values of 0, 1, 2. You will need to map these values back to 'yes', 'no', 'maybe'. To avoid overcomplicating things, you can just use a `map` on this new `DataFrame`:

```py
predictions["predicted_value"] = predictions["predicted_value"].map({0: 'yes', 1: 'no', 2: 'maybe'})
```

Now we need to merge these predictions back with the original `df`:

```py
df = df.merge(
    predictions, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer"
)
```

Comment: I have used mode.predict followed by np.argmax(), but it’s returning [0], whereas I have annotated the outputs as 1,2,3

Comment: [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) only gives you the *indices* of the largest values in your array, so it's not a surprise it's giving you 0 (it should give 0, 1, or 2 since your array dimension is 3). It will not give you the annotated values.

Comment: Something I noticed is that you're using `binary_crossentropy` for the loss function. Since this is not a binary classification problem, you might consider using something different, such as `categorical_crossentropy`. You also need to change your last `Dense` layer to have the same number of nodes as categories (3). I also typically use 'softmax' for the activation function of this last `Dense` layer. It will give you % values for each category (which sum to 1). You can use argmax the same way to find the category with the greatest likelihood.

Comment: you are right..I have updated the loss function.